# Can I pass a variable to the first parameter of @Html.Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to be able to call `@Html.Partial()` without knowing at design time what the partial file will be. I'd like to do something like...

In the Controller:

```
string partial;
switch (some_val) {
    case 1:
        partial = "help.cshtml";
        break;

    case 2:
        partial = "legal.cshtml";
        break;

    // Other cases here...

    default:
        partial = "default.cshtml";
        break;
}

ViewBag.partial = partial;
```

And in the View:

```
@Render.Partial (@ViewBag.partial)
```

...or...

```
@Render.Partial ("@ViewBag.partial")
```

Note, there is no Model.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: `@Render.Partial ((string)ViewBag.partial)`

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!